# Help identifying LED strip and its connectors

Tags: led-strip

Some years ago, I was given, what I assume is an LED strip by a friend.

I'm interested in building a "NeoPixel"-like solution for a Pi Pico and hope I can use this strip.

IIUC from trying to discern any details about the strip, it requires 12V DC to the black wire and the other 3 wires correspond to (R)ed, (G)reen and (B)lue.

My questions are:

- Can anyone tell me the manufacturer|SKU for this strip?
- What is the name of the converter from a wall wart 12V DC to the 4-pin RGB LED power strip?
- Where can I pick up these converters?
- Can I then safely connect the strip to the (black) power and the RGB wires to Pico outputs?
- Would I be better placed just buying a NeoPixel strip from Adafruit?

Thanks!

[image: Packaging (front)]
[image: Packaging (back)]
[image: LED strip]
[image: Power connector (male)]
[image: Power connector (female)]

Comment: This is not neopixel - You cannot contol each led individually. Whole strip will light with the same color.

Comment: Aha! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the kind of strip that can only glow in one colour for all LEDs. In other words, not addressable pixels.

There are RGB LEDs and it looks like one resistor for each color of LED per triplet of LEDs. So each triplet consists of 3 series LEDs of each of the 3 colors and one resistor.

To get various colors (other than the 7 binary combinations) you need a controller that PWMs the 3 controller outputs to ground with a power MOSFET.